# List can't access an object before it is initialized in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I created a house object to have member in a list called 'favHouses'. But dart doesn't let me to add those members before i initialize in constructor. Here is my code and the error that i get.

```dart
List<House> favHouses = [houseAlanya];
House houseAlanya = new House(..);
```

the error i get:

> The instance member 'houseAlanya' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
> dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Dart 2.12, you can use the `late` keyword for lazy initialization.

```dart
late List<House> favHouses = [houseAlanya];
```